# Click if image is found in c#

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

Alright Hello again, I need some more help. So i'm working with c# winforms and selenium FireFox Drivers.

Here is my current code.

```
IWebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
Bitmap image1 = (Bitmap) Image.FromFile(@"C:\BotProgect\image1.png", true);
driver.moveToElement(image1);
driver.Click();
```

What i need to do is click on the image from the file. This code isn't working at all Got errors. I need it to click the image1 and test if it exists before clicking. Thanks !

Errors Said

Error   1   'OpenQA.Selenium.IWebDriver' does not contain a definition for 'moveToElement' and no extension method 'moveToElement' accepting a first argument of type 'OpenQA.Selenium.IWebDriver' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)35   20

Error   2   'OpenQA.Selenium.IWebDriver' does not contain a definition for 'Click' and no extension method 'Click' accepting a first argument of type 'OpenQA.Selenium.IWebDriver' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) 36  20

Answer (score 2):

The errors u got are perfect and they are expected.

***MoveToelement*** - This function is supported by Actions class and it should be invoked on such object and not on *IWebDriver* object.

```
IWebElement Target_Elem= driver.FindElement(By.Id("ID_LOCATOR"));
Actions builder = new Actions(driver)
builder.MoveToElement(Target_Elem).Click().Build().Perform();
```

***Click*** - This function/method is performed over an *IWebElement* and not on the driver. Hence the right method to use is.

```
driver.FindElement(By.Id("ID_LOCATOR")).Click();
```

Comment: Alright this was perfect but how can i make it click on Image one?

Comment: Really need help on this.

Comment: sure..can u pls what issue u are facing??